# Why I get error when i write: using system.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Tags: c#, winforms, zip

I am trying to unzip a file with the siple method `zipfile`that requires `using system.IO.Compression.FileType`, but I always get an error, that there is no such a thing.

For those, who think I am using unsupported .NET Framework, **I am using version 4.5.2** and the `ZipFile` is supposed to work with the 4.5 version and later (as Microsft says).

Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
// using System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;

        private void InstallData()
        {
            pBar_Downloading.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            if (updater_main.AppLang == "cz")
            {
                lbl_text.Text = "Právě probíhá instalace aktualizace...";
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_text.Text = "Installing the update...";
            }

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(updater_main.AppLocation + "package.zip", updater_main.AppLocation);
        }
```

Comment: can you post some sample code?

Comment: sure, just wait a minute

Comment: Well for one thing it should be `System` rather than `system`... next, what makes you think `System.IO.Compression.FileType` is a namespace? `ZipFile` is just in `System.IO.Compression`... next, your title refers to `FileSystem` whereas your question body refers to `FileType`. Finally, I think you've got namespaces and assemblies confused. You need a *reference* to the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll` assembly, but `ZipFile` is in the *namespace* `System.IO.Compression`.

Comment: Actually I have the code as you say. I just entered it incorrectly when I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have told that you are already using version 4.5.2.

Go to References and add "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"

To add a reference in Visual C#

**1**.In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add Reference.

**2**.In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.

**3**.Select the components you want to reference, and then click OK.